# How to plot a PCOA biplot with OTU loadings as arrows

Tags: r, microbiome

I'm working on gut microbiota data. I want to perform a biplot showing my 2 enterotypes and the major OTU explaining the variance between my two enterotypes.

Something like : [image] from https://doi.org/10.1038/srep08397

I'm using the package ade4 to plot the enterotypes which gives me a nice plot but I can't find how to add the OTU loading

My script :

```
library(ade4)
#dist_jsd_3a = distance
#sample_data(physeq_genus_3a_epi)$cluster_3a_fullname) = enterotypes
#obs.pcoa$li = pcoa result from dudi.pco function

obs.pcoa=dudi.pco(cailliez(dist_jsd_3a), scannf=F, nf=2)
s.class(obs.pcoa$li, fac=as.factor(sample_data(physeq_genus_3a_epi)$cluster_3a_fullname), grid=F, col = c("#0073C2FF","#EFC000FF"))
```

this code gives me this plot : [image]

I also run this following code using the envfit function from vegan package which allowed me to plot the OTU but the resulting plot is not as pleasant as the one above with the s.class function from ade4 package.

```
library(vegan)
#dist_jsd_3a = distance
#groups = enterotypes
#pcoa = pcoa result from cmdscale(dis)

dis<-dist_jsd_3a
groups <- sample_data(physeq_genus_3a_epi)$cluster_3a
pcoa <- cmdscale(dis)
efit <- envfit(pcoa, t(otu_table(physeq_genus_3a_epi)))
plot(pcoa, col = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF")[groups], pch = c(21,24)[groups])
##Ordiellipse##
## I use confidence level of 0.95) ##
ordiellipse(pcoa, groups, col = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"),
            kind="sd",lty=c(1), conf = 0.95, alpha = 0.05, lwd = 2)

plot(efit, col = "red", cex = 0.9)
```

See the result here : [image]

I want to know if anyone already plotted a biplot using ade4 package and have been able to add arrows for OTU. If yes, any tips would be appreciated.